# Unable to install pip in Docker

Tags: docker, pip

Unable to install pip in Docker running Ubuntu version 14.04. See below log.

```
root@57da7dd8a590:/usr/bin# apt-get install pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
root@57da7dd8a590:/usr/bin#
```

Answer (score 17):

Did you do `apt-get update` before that?

And then

```
apt-get -y install python-pip
```

Comment: I sure did: `Reading package lists... Done / Building dependency tree / Reading state information... Done / All packages are up to date.` but still getting `unable to locate package python-pip`

Answer (score 5):

This is my Dockerfile. You would try it:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Storozhenko Roman <romeusmeister@gmail.com>
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-03-16

RUN apt-get -yqq update
RUN apt-get install -yqq python 
RUN apt-get -yqq install python-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are using the wrong package. You can install `pip` in Ubuntu 14.04 with

`apt-get install python-pip`

If youre searching for something you can use

`aptitude search pip`

or the Website http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: tvn I tried apt-get install python-pip and got the same response - E: Unable to locate package python-pip.

Comment: @NKD i think your container doesn't have internet connectivity can you ping google.com?

Comment: Then you probably should do an package update `apt-get update` before the install. This updates the package list and makes sure you choose the most recent version of the package of you choice. If even this don't work check your connectivity like @booyaa wrote with ping (`ping -c 5 google.com`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some issue with Ubuntu 14.04 version. I moved to 13.1 and then apt-get install python3-pip solved the issue. However, it installs not pip you get pip3. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

[python-pip](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python/python-pip) for Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) is in "universe" packages.

So, I had to do the following (as root):

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common 
add-apt-repository universe 
apt-get install -y python-pip
```

Comment: not sure how much clutter software-properties-common adds, but that add-apt-repository command is super handy. I'm sure there is a "raw" way to add the repository (like appending some lines to an apt file)...

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip in Ubuntu 15.10-x86_64 with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me: FROM python:3.7